# Css position fixed on header hides content

Tags: html, css, header, position

I am making a new website, and i have a problem with the header... I set the header's position to fixed, and that works but the content below the header is hidden. I tried to move the content down with `margin-top: 10px`, but all it did was move the header down.

**Link to jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/vwzhda41/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give `padding-top:58px;` to the `.responsiveContainer` and add `top:0;` to the `.header`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/vwzhda41/1/)

```
.responsiveContainer {
    width: 100%;
    // Add padding top
    padding-top: 58px;
}

.header {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #232323;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    //   Add top 0
    top: 0;
}
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> fixed
>
> **Do not leave space for the element.** Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it
>   when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on
>   every page. This value always create a new stacking context.

Comment: Thanks, this worked i will accept this as soon as possible.

Comment: won't fixed padding cause problems like too much space, when we shrink the window vertically and the header height changes?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
padding-top: 58px;/*the height of the header*/`
```

instead of

```
margin-top:10px;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need put the `<div class="header">` inside of a div with defined height, like:

```
<div class="heightTest">
<div class="header">
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.heightTest{height:90px;}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vwzhda41/2/

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* Copyright © 2015 Dynavio */

/* Main Site Settings */

*,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.responsiveContainer {
  width: 100%;
}
/* End Of Main Site Settings */

/* Header */

.header {
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #232323;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: #131313;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navElem {
  display: inline;
  margin: -2px;
}
.navLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: SinkinSans;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.navLink:hover {
  background-color: #0044FF;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #01268A;
}
.navLink:visited {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.active {
  background-color: #0044FF;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #01268A;
}
/* End Of Header */

/* Site Content */

.startBox {
  background-color: #0044FF;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
/* End Of Site Content */

/* Alignment Classes */

.alignLeft {
  text-align: left;
}
/* End Of Alignment Classes */
```

```html
<div class="responsiveContainer">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li class="navElem"><a href="#" class="navLink active">Home Page</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navElem"><a href="#" class="navLink">Our Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navElem"><a href="#" class="navLink">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navElem"><a href="#" class="navLink">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="startBox">
    <p>dwddwwdwdd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```